# Event handler cannot access Object method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, object, methods

How can I access util.log() method from a static html event handler?

In other words, when I click the checkbox, I like to call util.log method.

onclick="util.log(\'hey\')" <-- how to rewrite the event function here?

I know all the answers are correct down here but is it possible to access local methods while insert the html into innerHTML?

thank you

```
var utilities = function() {
 var util = this;

 util.log = function(msg){
  alert(msg);
 };

 var p = document.createElement('p');
 p.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" onclick="util.log(\'hey\')" value="1">Check me'; 
 // this part has to be plain html, because there is this table generator class 
 // will insert this to cell as innerHTML. That's why I can't change the table class. 
};
```

Comment: Do you want an alert saying "hey" when you click the checkbox?

Comment: yes, but eventually, how to call an object method from hard-coded events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `util` object is not in the global scope; it's hidden inside the `utilities` object. The click handler will run in the scope of the global object, which is why it can't see `util` at all.

If you can't change the way the HTML strings are created, then you'll need to declare `util` outside the `utilities` function, in other words, just this in the page:

```
 var util = {};
 util.log = function(msg){
  alert(msg);
 };

 var p = document.createElement('p');
 p.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" onclick="util.log(\'hey\')" value="1">Check me'; // this part is a legacy code and I have no control over to rewrite it as HTMLObjectElement way
```

Answer (score 1):

try this javascript instead:

```
var util = {
 log : function(msg){
  alert(msg);
 };
};
```